# Job run in sql sever agent insert all null data.

Tags: sql-server

I have a store procedure which  insert  data into a table in sql. It work find in  SQL however when i create a job in sql server management studio to execute this store procedure by

```
exec store procedure name
```

the job does run successfully but all the data insert into the table is null.

i have no idea how this happen, please help. Thanks

Comment: Might be a permission problem? Under which account is your sqlserver agent service running? What are it's permissions?

Comment: Thanks, I check the security i am set as the owner of the database account. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Part 1:***

We need to know more information than what you are supplying.

Here is a list of things to start.

```
1 - Generate TSQL for the table.

2 - Send us a couple of records to insert.

3 - Sample TSQL code inside the job step.

4 - What account is SQL Agent running under?

5 - Is the job running in the correct database when executing the TSQL statement?

6 - Are there any errors in the job history.
```

In short, this task can be easily done.

A screen shot or two would be worth a 1000 words!

***Part 2:***

Please use the snippet tool in windows to grab a screen shot so that I can see what is wrong.

It is very difficult to diagnose things remotely via just words.

Here are some more things to check.

```
1 - Are you a local admin of the laptop or server?

2 - Make sure you open the SQL server configuration manager as an admin.  

This can be accomplished by right clicking the icon and selecting run as an admin instead of a double click to launch.
```

Below is a sample image of my configuration manager.

[image]

Here is the status of my SQL Server agent and the account it is running under.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am so new to sql sever. I have trouble to find what account is SQL Agent running under?

Comment: I find my SQL server agent is not start in sql server configuration manager. But i do not know i can not start it. the Start button is grey out.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?  The local admin group and run as admin are the first places to look.  I think the first one is required, the second one is optional.